# Is it better to use index as key instead of Math.random() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, ecmascript-6

Following is my react code, which is displaying menu items and unfortunately I am not getting any id to add as a key in list. As mentioned in the docs  under [Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#keys) section, it is advised to avoid `Math.random()`. Is it performant and better than `Math.random()` to use index as key while displaying the menu list ?

Code -

```js
[{name: 'Home'}, {name: 'About'}, {name: 'News'}, {name: 'Contact'}].map((item, index) => {
    return `<li key=${index}>${item.name}</li>`
})
```

Comment: Of course it is more performant to just use the index instead of calling a function every time. It's unlikely though, that a user would notice that.

Comment: The docs already explain why you need a non-random key - because React expects a stable identity in order to detect changes to the same item. It's in the link you have. Besides, with that aside how are you going to ensure no collisions if you use random numbers?

Comment: If I was you, I wouldn't use either `math.random` or the `index` as a key. If the array changes, your keys get messed up and that will cause really strange behaviors in the diffing engine. Use something else, an auto incrementing ID would be a better solution if you can't find a good value.

Comment: If you are sure that the names are unique, just use them.

Comment: @LucaKiebel An index is just as useless as a random number, unless the items in your list will always have the same index (i.e. you never want to insert or delete an item in the middle or beginning of the list, or sort the list differently).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it simply I wouldn't use either. The point of the key is to allow React identify the children `<li>`s you are creating, during render.

Using the a random key or array index will not provide a consistent key.

I'd instead add an ID to each of your objects...

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Home' },
  { id: 2, name: 'About' },
  { id: 3, name: 'News' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Contact' },
].map(({ id, name }) => {
  return <li key={id}>{name}</li>
})
```

That way if your were to reorder the array, the ID consistently identifies the object.

Comment: When the list is going to be a set of unique values, there's nothing wrong with just using the `name` as a key. Of course if you can't assume that they are unique you shouldn't do this.