# "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" in React (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React (TypeScript) I am getting:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check
> the render method of `MyCollection`

This is `MyCollection`:

```
export default function MyCollection(props:any ) {
  let nodes = useSelector((state: any) => state.vpms.norm.nodes);
  // let node = useSelector((state: any) => state.vpms.norm.nodes[props.id]);
  const groupListAdapter: GroupListAdapter = useGroupList(props);
  let items: any = [];
  groupListAdapter.itemsIds().forEach((itemId:any) => {items.push(nodes[itemId])});

  return (
    <>
      {items.map(props.render)}
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is how it is called in the parent component:

```
export default function App() {
...

const id = (node: any, name: string) => nodes[node.c[name]].id;

return (
{iter(root, 'persons').map((persons: any, index: number) => { return (
<MyCollection id={id(persons, 'coverages')} 
    render= {(coverages: any, index: number) => (
        <Accordion id={coverages.id} isExpanded={true}  >
        <Grid columns={4} style={{width: "100%"}} >
         ....../>
...
)
```

How can I get a unique key to avoid this warning? Note that the prop `id` in `App` is a single id for all `items` in `MyCollection`.

Comment: What fields are available in `coverages`? If there is something unique in there, then that can be the key.

Comment: You omited the most important part of code for this question: `render={(coverages: any, index: number) => (.....` the part in dots needs to produce components that include a `key` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the index of the item when mapping like this

```
yourArray.map((item, itemIndex) => <SomeComponent key={itemIndex} />);
```

Though you really **should have a unique identifier for each item**. Because it's considered as an **anti-pattern** in React.

More info here:

- https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/
- https://medium.com/@muesingb/why-you-shouldnt-use-index-as-the-unique-identifier-of-a-component-in-react-b20c3bfcb786
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338203/14575901
- https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c

Answer (score 0):

You can use index as a key while mapping like :

```
list.map((item,index)=>{
return (
<p key={index}>Samle Text</p>
)
})
```